# Not connecting to server due to DNS or Netbios issue?

Tags: dns, netbios

Don't understand this COMP Tia Networking practice exam question:

Joe, a system administrator, is troubleshootng an issue with remotely accessing a new server on the LAN. He is using an LMHOST file and the file contains the hostname and IP address of the new server. The server that he cannot remote to is located on the same LAN as another server that he can successfully remote to. Which of the following
output from the command line would BEST resolve the problem?

```
A. C:\windows\system32>ipconfig /flushdns
Windows IP configuration Successfully flushed DNS resolver cache  

B. C:\windows\system32>ipconfig /registerdns
Windows IP configuration Registration of the DNS resource records for all adapters has been initiated. Any errors will be reported in the event viewer in 15 minutes.  

C. C:\windows\system32>nslookup
Default server: unknown Address: 1.1.1.1  

D. C:\windows\system32>nbtstat -R
Successful purge and reload of the NBT remote cache table
```

Answer : B

My question is why would it be better to assume it is a DNS problem with a server on your LAN and not a netbios issue.

Comment: Are the commands supposed to be run on the _server_ or on the _client_?

Comment: You cannot learn the material on the CompTIA Network+ exam by doing practice exams without first understanding the material. As for the usefulness of this question, I have been burned once from one of your questions, turns out your practice exam is full of errors. So I personally don't find "yet another give me the answer" question to be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. This is another question / answer pair that is incorrect.

You have to answer the question with the most obvious answer based on the information you’ve been given.

First, you can’t remote to the server, so obviously the commands suggested are being run on the administrator’s computer.

Because Answer B is directly related to registering the administrator’s computer IP address with DNS, it absolutely can’t be the right answer as that has no effect on being able to connect to another server/computer.

In addition, Answers A, B, and C all deal with DNS. Whereas the LMHOSTS file is for NetBios name resolution.

Therefore, the correct answer is D. Purge and reload the NetBios name cache.

Point of interest - Answer C reveals the administrator’s computer is using a public DNS server (1.1.1.1), further cementing the fact that DNS is NOT being used to resolve this server’s hostname to IP address.

Comment: I wouldn't immediately assume that Joe, being a system administrator, does not have direct console access to the server. (Or at least access which doesn't rely on hostnames; after all, Joe knows the IP address.)

Comment: And as we've discussed once already, using a public DNS server does not in any way make it impossible to resolve AD hostnames in the general case – that assumption is only valid if you know 100% that the AD domain hasn't been globally delegated (which would go against [Microsoft's recommendations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771849%28v%3dws.10%29#delegating-the-dns-zone-for-the-forest-root-domain)).

Comment: @grawity point taken on your second comment. I agree, but that was not the point of my answer, it was merely an observation that probably was meant to point someone to the correct answer. To both comments, the Net+ is a simple test. You cannot make assumptions outside of the information given. The question says the administrator can not connect to the server. The fact that it is vague at all about which system the commands are being typed on, makes this a poor quality question. The info provided here shows NetBios is being used and only one answer deals with NetBios at all.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I really appreciate your helping me with some of these practice questions.